# AIOHTTP having request body/content/text when calling raise_for_status

Tags: python, aiohttp, fastapi

I'm using `FastAPI` with `aiohttp`, I built a singleton for a persistent session and I'm using it for opening the session at startup and closing it at shutdown.

**Demand**: The `response` body is precious in **case of a failure** I must log it with the other details.

Because how `raise_for_status` behave I had to write those ugly functions which handle each HTTP method, this is one of them:

```
async def post(self, url: str, json: dict, headers: dict) -> ClientResponse:
    response = await self.session.post(url=url, json=json, headers=headers)
    response_body = await response.text()

    try:
        response.raise_for_status()
    except Exception:
        logger.exception('Request failed',
                         extra={'url': url, 'json': json, 'headers': headers, 'body': response_body})
        raise

    return response
```

If I could count on `raise_for_status` to return also the body (`response.text()`),
I just could initiate the session `ClientSession(raise_for_status=True)` and write a clean code:

```
response = await self.session.post(url=url, json=json, headers=headers)
```

Is there a way to force somehow `raise_for_status` to return also the payload/body, maybe in the initialization of the `ClientSession`?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible for `aiohttp` and `raise_for_status`. As @Andrew Svetlov answered [here](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3248):

> Consider response as closed after raising an exception.
> Technically it can contain a partial body but there is no any guarantee.
> There is no reason to read it, the body could be very huge, 1GiB is not a limit.
> If you need a response content for non-200 -- read it explicitly.

Alternatively, consider using the [httpx](http://www.python-httpx.org) library in this way. (It is widely used in conjunction with FastAPI):

```
def raise_on_4xx_5xx(response):
    response.raise_for_status()

async with httpx.AsyncClient(event_hooks={'response': [raise_on_4xx_5xx]}) as client:
    try:
        r = await client.get('http://httpbin.org/status/418')
    except httpx.HTTPStatusError as e:
        print(e.response.text)
```

Comment: Thank you, eventually, `httpx` winning the race, the `raise_for_status`, the support for async tests ...